# Finding a simple function for a given Karnaugh diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I came across one question in which the Karnaugh map for some function is given and using it, i have to find a simple function which gets mapped onto that map.[image]

My Attempt:

Corresponding to every shaded square there will be a boolean expression of the form, $0000,0010,1010,..$ etc.

What I did was that I added the minterms corresponding to those expressions which had value $1$ i.e. I added the minterms corresponding to $0000,0010,1010,1000,1011,1111,1101,1110$.

My questions:

First, i am not sure about, what, is actually meant by "$simple function$" here, does it simply mean that i have to add the minterms which have value $1$ and find a simplified expression or do i have to make pairs of ones in the karnaugh diagram and find the minimal form for the function ?

Second,will there be a unique simple function ? or would it depend on the way in which sequence $0's$ and$1's$ are chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your example (i) on the left:**
The four top-row squares are covered by $b_2\land b_4'$.
Similarly, the second column from the right is covered by $b_1' \land b_3$.
Now, there is only one square left to be covered: $b_1' \land b_2' \land b_3' \land b_4$.
But this can be simplified to $b_1' \land b_2' \land b_4$ by omitting $b_3'$ and combining it with the already covered column.

The resulting simple function is a disjunction of conjunctions:

$$(b_2\land b_4') \lor (b_1' \land b_3) \lor (b_1' \land b_2' \land b_4)$$

**A similar reasoning for example (ii) on the right**
also leads to a sum of three expressions:

$$(b_1 \land b_2) \lor (b_1' \land b_2' \land b_4) \lor (b_1' \land b_2' \land b_3')$$

"Simple" usually means "minimum number of terms and/or literals". The selection of terms is not always unique, but in your examples, there are no other choices which exhibit the same number of terms.

Comment: I understand your answer, but is the way i proceeded wrong ? Can't the sequences of $0's$ and $1's$ be used ?

Comment: Basically, you have to group adjacent 1 entries to blocks. Each square corresponds to a minterm. The simplification means to subsume several minterms into a term with fewer literals. Ask Google for "define minterm" to get better explanations.